# After migration to H2 version 2.0 can not generate a database in H2 format

Tags: java, h2

Using H2 version 1.3 my code used to create a new in-file H2 database.
It was generated by invocation

```
dataSource.getConnection()
```

where dataSource URL points to a non-existent file:

```
url='jdbc:h2:file:C\DEV\test'
```

As a result a file C\DEV\test.h2.db was generated.

After upgrating to H2 version 2.0 the same code generates a file test.mv.db instead.

I tried to add a parameter `MV_STORE=FALSE` to the url string, then nothing is created.

Dependencies in pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.16</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.202</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>3.28.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Can you help, how can I create a file in H2 format using version 2.0?

Comment: Have you read the [H2 version 2 migration docs](https://www.h2database.com/html/migration-to-v2.html)? The format is *mostly* the same, but there have been some changes. The docs describe how to move from the old format to the new format.

Comment: @moshe-katz I have read the doc, but there is about how to convert the existing db to version 2. But I need to create it dinamically.

Comment: `.h2.db` extension is used by historic PageStore engine, it was removed from H2, you cannot read or write files in that format even with outdated H2 2.0.202.